# Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/mipmap-anydpi-v26/leak_canary_icon.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f030019

Tags: android, leakcanary

Use version：com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:2.4

No configuration has been added

The following error occurs when opening the **leakcanary** app：

```
     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{cn.ledongli.ldl/leakcanary.internal.activity.LeakActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable cn.ledongli.ldl:mipmap/leak_canary_icon with resource ID #0x7f030019
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3388)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3527)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2123)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7710)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:516)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable cn.ledongli.ldl:mipmap/leak_canary_icon with resource ID #0x7f030019
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/mipmap-anydpi-v26/leak_canary_icon.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f030019
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:888)
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:671)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity(Resources.java:906)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:845)
        at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:687)
        at com.android.internal.widget.ToolbarWidgetWrapper.setIcon(ToolbarWidgetWrapper.java:322)
        at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.setIcon(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:754)
        ...
```

Comment: you mean leakcanary app itself crashing?

Comment: Yes, do I need to add ICONS manually?